# Using value " null" in HTML attributes

Tags: html, tags, attr

I am using HTML attributes to bind data. Framework CanJS.

```
I am using a `<div data-name="<%= items[1]%>"><%= items[1]%></div>` tag in file ejs
```

With attr name is data-name have value is "null" (items[1] = "null").

First point : If you using <%= items[1]%> type (one "=")is data display as below:

```
<div data-name=""">"</div>
```

Second point : If you using <%== items[1]%> type (two "=") is data display as below:

```
<div data-name=""">null</div>
```

I do not know why, data-name display so ("). Thank you!

Comment: `<%= items[1]%>` is not HTML. You should specify what languages you are using, at least by tagging your question with their names.

Comment: You are not showing data display, just HTML code. And it is not clear at all what you mean by “null”. The 4-letter string “null”, or the empty string, or a null pointer, or what? Besides, from the example it seems that the value is actually “"” (the Ascii quotation mark).

Comment: Hi  Jukka K. Korpela,
I am using framework CanJS. That is file index.ejs
http://canjs.com/index.html